# Role Assignment showing Type as Manage User instead of Role

Tags: openidm

While provisioning role to the user from the User details page it is giving Issue as Role Assignment showing Type as Manage User instead of Role and description also not coming.

But it works well when assigned the same role via Roles details page

[image: Role Assignment showing Type as Manage User instead of Role]

Comment: Can you share the configuration of your role? And what version of OpenIDM are you using?

Comment: @LaurentBristiel thanks for your response, I am using openidm-4.0.0 version and I am new to openidm and trying to assign role from both the User Details page and role details page. I have not done any special configuration for the same.